Which of these circuits implements an arithmetic right shift (Y = A >>> shamt)?
I am stuck with this exercise question:
Given are 3 circuits with 2 inputs: a 4-bit number A3:0 = A3A2A1A0 and a 2-bit number
shamt1:0. Which of these circuits implements an arithmetic right shift (Y = A >>> shamt)?
There are those 4 multiplexers but how can they determine the right shift arithmetic result?

Think about what can happen to the most significant bit. Only one of those circuits can do that.

Hi! I understand that the upper bit should have either the option to be 0 or 1. I assume the outcome of the first multiplexer (Y3) is the MSB of my result?
But I don't really know how to go from there....

You need to ask a detailed question.  Best to show your work and indicate where your stuck in your question.  If you don't we don't know where you're stuck, i.e. what shifting means, how to read these diagrams, etc..

Alternatively, we know that during an arithmetic right shift explicit zeroes don't appear anywhere. But two of the circuits produce zeroes so those can't be right.

You're using the >>> token, which is usually logical/unsigned shift (e.g. as in Java), but you state arithmetic right shift in text.  Suggest to re-examine your notation/terms, because the definition of what shift does depends on this.

What confuses me is the meaning of these lines in general ? So for example , in the first part with Y3, I can either have the bit of A3, A2, A1 or A0 as my result's MSB. ? If we set the multiplexer to 00, for instance, how do we know whether the first multiplexer takes the bit of A3 , A2, A1 or A0?

Sorry for the confusion, I do mean an arithmetic right shift.

It's written on the multiplexer which input is for which combination. 00 is the first input, whichever A bit it is connected to.

The mux has labels for the matching input values, so for the top left, if you apply a shift amount of 00, then you'll get A3 as Y3.

I'm also not sure what the little triangle at the bottom of A and B refer to :(

That is ground (zero).

I believe that triangle represents ground, which means a constant value, probably 0, but could be 1 depending on the logic being used.

"The mux has labels for the matching input values, so for the top left, if you apply a shift amount of 00, then you'll get A3 as Y3."
But since this line is also connected to A2, A1 and A0, how do we know that we will get A3 instead? Since the line from 00 is connected to all A values?

You have to forgive the poor quality of the drawing.  Forking/splitting of lines (as in T shape) should be taken seriously but crossing of lines (as in + shape) are hops over instead of joins.

So does 00 in the multiplexer mean I don't shift at all, 01 -> I shift right by one bit , 10 -> I shift right by two bits, 11 -> I shift right by 3 bits?
If I choose one option, e.g. 01, that means I apply 01 in each of these 4 multiplexers right? Because it's just that one signal running from top to bottom?
I am still confused as to how I can make use of the information that the upper bit can either be 0 or 1.

(Joins are not really possible in the hardware — only through circuit such as a mux or logic gate, e.g. and, or, nor, nand, ... can we combine/join lines.  However forking/splitting is easy to do in hardware but joins take a circuit or gate; so we take line crossings as hops.)

Yes, in Y = A >> shamt, we would take shamt==00 to mean no shift.  shamt==01 is one bit to the right, 10 two bits, 11 three bits.  And yes, each mux gets the same shamt value.

You make use of the information that the top bit has to fill the result for 11.

what do you mean by fill the result for 11?

All the output bits must be A3. Since A3 A2 A1 A0 >> 3 = A3 A3 A3 A3. Only one of those circuits do this.

ok i understood it now!! thanks a lot!

This question seems more appropriate for [electronics.se].
